# Make video of ipad application

Tags: iphone, macos, video, video-capture

I need a video of my ipad application. It should be in high resolution and preferably make feeling of natural using of application(so, no cursor, etc). What is the best way to do this and what tools should I use ? I am using Mac. Antoher question is: what is better - to capture video from simulator or from iPad ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use screenflow to record HD movies from your screen (using simulator). Then change the cursor arror for a realistic finger using a little open source program called phoneFinger. Cant remember the URL but just google phonefinger.

Comment: phoneFinger is really a nice tool ! Unfortunately screenflow(and other programms I tried) outputs not the quality I wanted. I really doubt that it is possible to make video with HD quality.

Comment: Actually playing with screenFlow's configuration, you can record at 720 and up to 60 fps.

Answer (score 0):

I use [Jing](http://www.techsmith.com/jing.html) for this purpose. It captures a screen-region of your choice. However, i am not sure how well it performs if you need to capture a video of high framerate apps (e.g. games, videoplayers, etc.).

Comment: As I remember Jing outputs .swf video and I need HD quality video, if it's possible.
I need to capture just static pages and video player.

Comment: @user801255 Their page says that the pro version can output h.264. You might want to give it a new try.

Answer (score -1):

it is similar to Iphone app development.

1. Drag the desired video file to resourse folder.
2. get the media player framework.
3. implementation:

`NSURL *name=[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResourse:,ofType:];`

```
MPMoviePlayerVeiwController *name= [[MPMoviePlayerVeiwController alloc]initWithContentURL:url];

[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated: name];

name.moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MVMovieSourceTypeFile;
[name.moviePlayer play];
```

Comment: this is how to play video in the application and I need to make demo video OF my application